# Auto scrolling a textArea with scrolllRectToVisible

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea, jviewport

So I've set up a JTextArea inside a scroll pane and with the button I've set up, each time I click it I want the view of the textarea to drop down one line. (So with two clicks at the top of the JTextArea is line 3).

I understand the best way to do this is with the .scrollRectToVisible(); idea but I am really struggling to execute it as I can't get my head around the rectangles side of it.

Would love any kind of help, thanks!

```
    int scrollPanePosition = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue());

    //and then in the method that responds to my button 
    //(it didn't work at all but i thought this was the right idea).
    {
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBar(scrollPanePosition + 1); 
    scrollPanePosition = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
    }
```

Comment: No idea if it will work. But maybe using the 'ensureIndexIsVisible()' will do the trick? It shields you from having to calculate row height and such.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Comment: That code snippet is not an SSCCE.  Don't put code in comments, [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16045206/418556) & use code formatting.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Think that should be good